# Who is the king in this painting from "Crusader Kings 2: A Game of Thrones" mod?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, character-identification

Playing the *Crusader Kings 2: A Game of Thrones* mod, I see this loading screen quite a lot:

[image: Loading screen, king knighting a kneeling man]

Is this a real king and if so who is it?

Comment: What do you mean by "real king"?

Answer (score 21):

That's Aegon IV Targaryen, knighting his bastard son Daemon Waters. He then gave him the sword, Blackfyre, which Daemon took for his name. It's drawn by [Marc Simonetti](https://marcsimonetti.deviantart.com/), for [*The World of Ice and Fire*](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_World_of_Ice_%26_Fire) where the caption reads:

> The knighting of Daemon Blackfyre by his father, King Aegon IV.

The image and description is also hosted on [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/File:Marc_Simonetti_knightingson.jpg).

Comment: There is an actual GoT character called *Daemon Blackfyre*? Is there also one called xXVenomLordXx?

Answer (score 9):

It is a very real one, King [Aegon IV Targaryen](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_IV_Targaryen), and it's on a loading screen not only because he is an important king but because it's an important event: he is currently knighting his bastard son, [Daemon I Blackfyre](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_I_Blackfyre). After that, he gave him [Blackfyre](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Blackfyre), making him the implicit heir to the throne. This is the first event of the [Blackfyre rebellion](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/First_Blackfyre_Rebellion).

Bonus: some other loading screen explanations.

[Field of Fire](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Field_of_Fire), a battle where Aegon the conqueror won against the Kings of the Rock and Reach.

[image: Field of Fire, dragon spitting fire on foot soldiers]